# Listener for moving away from input box

Tags: javascript

I have two HTML `input` boxes, and I want to make them so that whenever the user finishes typing in the first box (and moves away from it -- say, by hitting "Tab" or clicking the mouse outside the area), the number is copied over into the second box. What JavaScript/JQuery mouse listener should I use, and how can I use it?

Comment: You're looking for the `blur` event.

Comment: look it up, rather than asking the same question again. google.com "blur javascript"

Comment: I didn't want to blur... I just edited to make clearer.

Comment: yes, you're looking for blur... blur means they had the input in focus, and now it is no longer -- i.e. they 'moved away from it' .... please, just google 'blur javascript'. Or, http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: What is your criteria for **"when the user finishes typing"**? And when you hit tab, it actually calls the `blur` event.

Comment: By the way, you are not literally blurring, but attaching something on the event of blur, which is losing focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments suggest, you really want blur, see [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DHXGQ/)

If you have troubles to put the code together...

```
<input type="number" id="from"/>
<input type="number" id="to"/>

<script>
document.getElementById("from").addEventListener("blur",function(e) {
    document.getElementById("to").value = e.target.value;
});
</script>
```